# How can I import bundlrStorage in metaplex library in js?

Tags: metaplex-js, javascript, bundlr

I've tried to use `bundlrStorage` but can' find where should I import it.

```
const Metaplex = require('@metaplex-foundation/js');
//
//
//
const MPX = Metaplex.Metaplex.make(connection).use(Metaplex.keypairIdentity(fromWallet)).use(Metaplex.Metaplex.nftStorage());
```

These are dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.20.1",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.0",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.90.0",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version does not support the bundler. You can downgrade to a previous version of Metaplex.

"@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.18.3",